# what is the best way to call parent variables from a callback function

Tags: angularjs, callback

I have a simple question but I want to be sure of the most concise way to do the task since I've seen answers here that seem long winded for something so simple.

How do i make the variables "inputKey" and "sigInput" available inside the callback function?

```
var moveValue = function(inputKey){
  var sigInput = $scope.signature[inputKey];

  repeatForAllGroupSignatures($scope.current.groupName, function(i) {
    console.log(inputKey);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript uses hoisting so the compiler looks for the variable inside the function first. If it is not there it looks into the parent function and so on.

In this example both inputKey and sigInput should be available inside the anonymous function used in the callback.

MDN does a pretty good job of explaining it here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var